# SO mobile site showing scrollbars

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, design, mobile-web

Running:
Android 10
OnePlus 5
Brave Browser

I'm seeing these scrollbars when opening the site.
The first one seems like more of an issue in Portrait mode:
[image]

In landscape, the side bar just auto opens with the scrollbar, which isn't really an issue, just makes it messy  IMO:
[image]

Issue doesn't appear on meta.

Comment: The first one is "by design", the second on the other hand... maybe by design? i don't get that one with my current settings.

Comment: @KevinB the first is by design?! I assume you mean they wanted "Products" front and centre? They could surely work with the pixels they have to avoid the scrollbar nonetheless.

Comment: well, that, and the list on the right is rather large anyway. Even on non-SO where "Products" isn't there, it can still have a scroll bar in some scenarios